# Power Point Slide and table Automation

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

I am new to VBA and PPT usage.

But here is my use case 1:

I have a presentation with a few slides. I want to automate those slides that have tables. I can set up the information that the table has directly from an excel. But when I copy those tables from the PPT to excel, the formatting especially the columns and rows and merged cells are absolutely out of order. Possibly because of the difference between the two sources. How can I do this?

Can i write a VBA code to pick up information from the PPT table directly from excel or any other way but I would avoid recreating the table in excel again as the PPT format should not change.

Use Case 2:

I have a PPT with 6-7 Slides, I want to make multiple copy presentations of the same PPT slides into like 30 PPT's and only want to change the text on the title page that can come from an excel list and the names of the 30 PPT's should also be from the same excel list?  I was trying to do this but got stuck.

Appreciate the help!

I was trying to make a code but was not successful.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried. It is much easier to write code for Excel that manipulates Powerpoint as the documentation for Excel is much better.

Comment: Welcome user23524065! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example